# Explain the code - SSL

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

Can any one please explain the below code (labeled "HERE").

1. `Keystore.load()` performs what?
2. Why `KeyManagerFactory` is used?

I need practical oriented solution.

```
System.setProperty("1", "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre");

String jrehome = System.getProperty("1");
String path = jrehome + "/" + "lib" + "/" + "security" + "/" + "cacerts";
char[] ksPass= "changeit".toCharArray();

try {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); // <- HERE
    System.out.println(ks.toString());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), ksPass);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, ksPass);

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    System.out.println(ks.getCertificate("SunX509"));
    tmf.init(ks);

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.getClientSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1);
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();

    SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888); // <-- HERE

    System.out.println("Server started:");
}
```

Comment: You should read the documentary of each class and ask more specific questions.

Comment: i am already read the documentation.i need explanation not suggestion.

Comment: "Documentation", not "documentary" ... Also, do not use a Windows library path to reference your JDK, instead follow a more practical; cross-platform method i.e. *`"%JAVA_HOME%/Contents/Home/jre"`*.

Comment: take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html And http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/KeyManagerFactory.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not shown any research into his questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Keystore.load()` is a mandatory call for accessing a keystore else you cannot acces it. The Javadoc says so. Once the keystore has been loaded, it is possible to read existing entries from the keystore, or to write new entries into the keystore. You have some overloaded method for `load()`.
2. `KeyManagerFactory` is a class that follows Factory pattern which creates Key Manager instances for managing a specific type of key material for use by secure sockets.